# Undefined Method URL for Action Mailer Attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

The Error I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `url' for nil:NilClass)
```

I have this attachment that is comming up nil

```
<%= image_tag attachments['tippedlogods.png'].url %>
```

That being said, I have declared the attachment in the method to send the email, here:

```
  def confirmation(order)
    @order = order
    mail(to: @order.email, subject: "Order Confirmation", content_type: "text/html")
    attachments.inline['tippedlogods.png'] = File.read("app/assets/images/tippedlogods.png")
  end
```

In my production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'hidden-peak-xxxx.heroku.com', :only_path => false}
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'hidden-peak-xxxx.heroku.com'
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address    => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
  :port       => 587,
  :user_name  => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
  :password   => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
  :domain     => ENV['SENDGRID_DOMAIN'],
  :authentication  => :plain
  }
```

Is this not the way to go about sending an image in a confirmation email?

I was following RoR Guides [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/action_mailer_basics.html)...

**Note** Rails 4~

Comment: The link was to Rails 3. Maybe something changed? Here is relevant section: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#complete-list-of-action-mailer-methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are calling `mail` first before you add the attachment. So there is no attachment when it renders the template!

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionMailer/Base/mail

Change the order of statements.

```
attachments.inline['tippedlogods.png'] = File.read("app/assets/images/tippedlogods.png")
mail(to: @order.email, subject: "Order Confirmation", content_type: "text/html")
```